# Why only get tr of table at first time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want get row of table 2 add to table 1, this is my js code:

```
$('#btnAdd').click(function () {

    var table = $('#table1');   
    var tr =$("#table2 tr");   
    table.append(tr);

    return false;
});
```

This is html code :

```
<div style="display: none;" id="rowitem">
    <table id="table2">
        <tr>
            <td>No1</td>
            <td>No2</td>
            <td>No3</td>          
        </tr>
    </table>

</div>
<div>
 <table id="table1">
        <tr>
            <td>No1</td>
            <td>No2</td>
            <td>No3</td>          
        </tr>
    </table>
  <input id="btnAdd" type="button" value="+"/>
</div>
```

At first time, it get `tr` and add `row` ok.

But if i click add again, `tr =undefined`

Why can't get row of table, if click next time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
$('#btnAdd').click(function () {

    var table = $('#table1');   
    var tr =$("#table2 tr").clone();   
    table.append(tr);

    return false;
});
```

Instead of copying the `tr`'s you are moving it

Answer (score 3):

The issue is by appending, you are moving the whole `tr` element that causes the `tr` unavailable after first click. You should append the cloned table with [`.clone()`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/):

```js
$('#btnAdd').click(function () {

    var table = $('#table1');   
    var tr = $("#table2 tr").clone();   
    table.append(tr);

    return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="display: none;" id="rowitem">
    <table id="table2">
        <tr>
            <td>No1</td>
            <td>No2</td>
            <td>No3</td>          
        </tr>
    </table>

</div>
<div>
 <table id="table1">
        <tr>
            <td>No1</td>
            <td>No2</td>
            <td>No3</td>          
        </tr>
    </table>
  <input id="btnAdd" type="button" value="+"/>
</div>
```